# why does python write to a file in gibberish characters

Tags: python, character-encoding

I attempted [Problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10)  at project euler and passed but I decided, *what if i wote all the prime numbers below 2 million to a text(.txt) file* and so I continued and so made some small adjustments to the main function which solved the problem so without just adding it to a variable(tot) I wrote the prime number which was generated by a generator to a text file and it at first worked but forgot to add spaces after each prime number, so the output was sort of gibberish

> 357111317192329313741434753

so I modified my `txt.write(str(next_prime))` to `txt.write(str(next_prime) + ' ')`

after that slight modification, the output was completely gibberish

> ″‵‷ㄱㄠ″㜱ㄠ‹㌲㈠‹ㄳ㌠‷ㄴ㐠″

here's my complete code for the function:

```
def solve_number_10():
    total = 2
    txt = open("output.txt","w")
    for next_prime in get_primes(3):
        if next_prime < 2000000:
            txt.write(str(next_prime) + ' ')
            #total += next_prime
        else:
            print "Data written to txt file"
            #print total
            txt.close()
            return
```

Why does this happen and how could I make the output like

```
3 5 7 11 13 17 19
```

Comment: what are you using to read the file? windows notepad? It has a well known longstanding will-not-be-fixed but that makes it misinterpret certain normal plaintext files as UTF-16, causing it to show those types of chars: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts

Comment: Potentially relevant: What version of Python? I think @MarcB has likely hit the issue, though.

Comment: "but forgot to add spaces after each prime number, so the out output was sort of gibberish" -- kind of like you forgot to use punctuation/capitalization in that whole run-on sentence thing?

Comment: I mean't **"output"** not "out output" isn't it obvious? and not relevant to the topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in Microsoft's Notepad program, not in your code.

```
>>> a = '‵‷ㄱㄠ″㜱ㄠ‹㌲㈠‹ㄳ㌠‷ㄴ㐠'
>>> a.decode('UTF-8').encode('UTF-16LE')
'5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 4'
```

Oh hey, look, they're prime numbers (I assume 4 is just a truncated 43).

You can work around the bug in Notepad by

1. Using a different file viewer that doesn't have the bug.
2. Write a ZWNBSP, once, to the beginning of the file, encoded in UTF-8:

   ```
   txt.write(u'\uFEFF'.encode('UTF-8'))
   ```

   This is incorrectly called a BOM.  It would be a BOM in UTF-16, but UTF-8 is not technically supposed to have a BOM.  Most programs ignore it, and in other programs it will be harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
txt.write('%i ' % next_prime)
```

Looks like `str()` is converting your number to a *character* that matches it in some encoding, and not to its string representation.